# Approximation of the norm of the powers of this random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, numerical-linear-algebra, random-matrices

This is from example 35.1 in *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau.

Suppose that $ B $ is a 200 x 200 real matrix with entries i.i.d from $ \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) $ where $ \sigma = 0.5/\sqrt{200} $.  Let $ A = 2I + B $.  The eigenvalues of $ A $ are approximately uniformly distributed in the disk of radius 1/2 centered at $ z = 2 $ in the complex plane.  The matrix $ I -A/2 $ is then a random matrix scaled so that its spectrum approximately fills the disk of radius 1/4 centered at $ z = 0 $.  The authors then claim that this justifies the following: $ \|(I-A/2)^n\|_2 \approx 4^{-n} $.  Why is this?

It seems like this should be relatively straightforward, and I must be missing something obvious.  In attempting to figure this out, I've come across the formula: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|C^n\|^{1/n} = \rho(C) $, where $ \rho $ is the spectral radius of $ C $.  However, the claim as stated applies to $ n = 1,2,3,\ldots $.

Thanks!

[Edit] In particular, I don't see why the knowledge that the eigenvalues of $ I - A/2 $ are approximately evenly spread over the disk of radius 1/4 centered at $ z = 0 $ implies that $ \|(I-A/2)^n\|_2 \approx 4^{-n} $.

Comment: I'm not sure why the eigenvalues of $A$ are approximately uniformly distributed in the disk of radius $1/2$ centred at $z=2$. It does not seem to work in simulation, which produces a large positive eigenvalue of roughly $400$.

Comment: @DanielBeale The statistical properties of these particular matrices are governed by the [circular law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law)

Comment: @DanielBeale In MATLAB: `m = 200; A = 2*eye(m) + 0.5*randn(m)/sqrt(m);`  I plotted the eigenvalues in the complex plane and saw that they are indeed nearly uniformly distributed in the disk centered at $ z = 2 $ with radius of 1/2.

Comment: If you then do `Spectrum = eig(I - A/2); max(Spectrum)` it should give you roughly $-1+200i$.

Comment: @DanielBeale In MATLAB, `I` is `0+1i`, so you should run `max(eig(eye(m) - A/2))` and get  a number with magnitude approximately 0.25.

Comment: OK. $A$ is defined as a matrix with values which are i.i.d $\mathcal{N}(2,\sigma^2)$. The matrix that you defined in matlab is of the form $A = 2I + B$, where $b_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Is that what it says in the book?

Comment: Good catch.  That is definitely a typo in the book.  I'm certain he's referring to the matrix as I've defined it which shifts the disk of radius 1/2 of approximately uniformly spread eigenvalues so that it's centered at $ z = 2 $.  I've edited the question.

Comment: You do have that $\| A \|$ is equal to the largest singular value $\sigma_{max}$. If the matrix $A$ is symmetric, then $\sigma_{max} = \max_{i}|\lambda_{i}|$, the spectral radius. In this case it would roughly equal $\frac{1}{4^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I've concluded that the claim is false.

It should be that $ \|(I-A/2)^n\|_2 \approx 2(4^{-n})$.  I don't want to get too far into random matrix theory, but apparently we have that for large $ n $ and $ X_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) $, $ \|X\|_2 \approx 2 \sigma \sqrt{n} $ and $ \rho(X) \approx \sigma \sqrt{n} $.  Theorem 1.1 in this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.5493&rep=rep1&type=pdf) justifies the first approximation.  The second approximation is justified because the eigenvalues of $ X $ are distributed uniformly across the disk of radius $ \sigma \sqrt{n} $, so the largest eigenvalue in absolute value will likely be near the edge of the disk.  Combining, we have that $ \|X\|_2 \approx 2\rho(X) $.

The random matrix $ I - A/2 $ has the same eigenvalue distribution as $ X $ where $ X_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 0.25/\sqrt{200}) $.  The $n$th power of $ X $ has eigenvalues spread roughly uniformly over the disk of radius $ \rho(X)^n $, so $ \|(I-A/2)^n\|_2 \approx 2(4^{-n}) $.